# Know the fibre model with an SFP with diagnostic

Tags: fiber, sfp

We're using our fibre links with 1G. We would like to move to 10G with this fiber but we have to know if it can support it.

It has been installed 10 years ago and we can't find the model. Is there any other way to know the model? Like an SFP with digital diagnostic or anything like that? I'm not looking for an SFP for statistics but just to know the model.

Comment: You could post a picture of the SFP for us to maybe give a more exact answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the cable for any markings. Usually you can then find the type by Google. Additionally, your switch should show which kind of SFP is inserted, regardless of DOM.

What's the approximate length of the cable?

Multi-mode (orange patch cable) supports 1000BASE-SX GbE for a few hundred meters (FDDI: 220m, OM1: 275m, OM2+: 550m). From ten years ago it's probably OM2 or OM3.

For 10GBASE-SR the ranges reduce to FDDI: 26m, OM1: 33m, OM2: 82m, OM3: 300m, OM4: 400m. If you require more reach on FDDI to OM2 you could try 10GBASE-LX4 (550m) but it is rare and costly. These reaches are by standard, you can often go somewhat further, depending on the exact fiber quality.

For single-mode fiber (yellow patch cable), you're probably good to go. 10GBASE-LR has the same reach as 1000BASE-LX(10) and you can buy higher-power transceivers with more reach.

On HP switches, you can query the transceiver models by `show interface transceiver detail` - *1000SX* stands for 1000BASE-SX (multi-mode) and so on. For 1000BASE-LX transceivers (single-mode), those equipped with DOM may show the Tx and Rx powers which gives you some estimate to what the link attenuation is.

Answer (score 0):

wich type of fiber you are using, for 10G you need to use OM2 / OM3 fiber ( for multimode fiber)

http://www.cablek.com/technical-reference/fiber-optic-cable-types

also you need to check the type of SFP (LR/SR) installed on the concerned interface ( with performing show interface transceiver details on cisco )

More details on the below link :

https://info.hummingbirdnetworks.com/blog/answering-your-frequently-asked-questions-about-different-types-of-10-gigabit-cisco-sfp-units

you can also know the type of fiber by color ( for ex Multimode  (OM2)  is Orange )

http://www.thefoa.org/tech/ColCodes.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need some fiber tester devices like a light meter or an OTDR. And then to compare the optical TX and RX levels on both sides. It would be ok if the signal is within range. Here is a document that may be useful to you: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/DOM_matrix.html